# TypeScript type is incorrect only when it's imported

Tags: javascript, typescript

This works:

```
export interface EditorFunctions {
  getEditor: () => Editor
}
    
const editorFunctions: EditorFunctions = {
  getEditor() {
    return editor;
  ,
}
```

The problem happens if I move the type declaration into a separate file:

types.ts:

```
export interface EditorFunctions {
    getEditor: () => Editor;
}
```

Main ts file:

```
import type {EditorFunctions} from "$lib/write/types";

const editorFunctions: EditorFunctions = {
  getEditor() {
    return editor;
  },
}
```

Then it shows the following error:

> Initializer type {getEditor(): Editor} is not assignable to variable
> type EditorFunctions

Why?

Comment: Aren't your declarations different? I mean, in the first case you declare "EditorFunctions" as an interface and in the second case as a type?

Comment: @Nikolay oh that doesn't make a difference but good spot. I fixed it in my post. The error persists though, no matter if it's a type or interface

Comment: Where is `editor` defined? Which you are returning? Can you reproduce it here https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-satoshi-tu38yu?file=/src/files.ts?

Comment: Is this the full error message? Usually there's some explanation about which fields exactly are incompatible. Can you show the full `tsc` output please?

Comment: Is the type of the `editor` variables the same `Editor`?

Comment: it's still different. You are using import type, this is a special construct. Have you tried to import just the interface. Meaning `import {EditorFunctions} from "$lib/write/types"`?